# How to make factory data available before controller loads page in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am making an `$http` call using factory and sharing the data to all controllers.

Actually I am getting that data from `config.json` file, but first on load data is not getting broadcasted to all controllers.
I want data to be available before controller can make further calls inside.

My `config.json` has `app_key`, `app_secret`, `base_url` etc, here is my factory (JS code)

## JS

```
.factory('UserService', function($http, $rootScope) {
     
    $http.get('config.json').success(function(data) {
        var app_key = data.app_key;
        var app_secret = data.app_secret;
        var base_url=data.base_url;
        window.localStorage['app_key'] = app_key;
        window.localStorage['app_secret'] = app_secret;
        window.localStorage['base_url'] = base_url;
     
       
    })

    return {
        app_key : window.localStorage['app_key'],
        app_secret : window.localStorage['app_secret'],
        base_url:window.localStorage['base_url'],
       
    }
})
```

my config.json file looks like this

```
{
    "app_key" : "my_app_key_here",
    "app_secret" : "my_app_secret_here",
    "base_url" : "http://base_url.com",
}
```

The reason I am returning app_key: window.localStorage['app_key'] is just because I need to access this service data like userService.app_key in controller.

```
ngoApp.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$localStorage', '$state','UserService','$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $state, UserService, $rootScope) {
 //I want to access app_key as below format
$scope.app_key=UserService.app_key;
}]);
```

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I am making?

Answer (score -1):

The right place where to load this dependencies is in your module run/config method.

Check documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies for example and more information...

Comment: Hi @elCarda thanks for the reply, can you please provide me any fiddle or small example to make such call?